# How to convert hex string to byte array in Java

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

I want to convert an hex string to byte array, I know these type of questions are already asked, I have tried their solution, But these solutions are not working with the library I'm using, I'm trying to convert the string

```
0x049e520ba27332ffed59ec7a34f744d4acd86ad22081d16f851d9f355ac09a70bdc14219c33ba7f5df62391a6f0f067c571bd6c03e83f81cd166e55fe043426a1c
```

To an byte array but the byte array I get is as

```
[48, 120, 48, 52, 57, 101, 53, 50, 48, 98, 97, 50, 55, 51, 51, 50, 102, 102, 101, 100, 53, 57, 101, 99, 55, 97, 51, 52, 102, 55, 52, 52, 100, 52, 97, 99, 100, 56, 54, 97, 100, 50, 50, 48, 56, 49, 100, 49, 54, 102, 56, 53, 49, 100, 57, 102, 51, 53, 53, 97, 99, 48, 57, 97, 55, 48, 98, 100, 99, 49, 52, 50, 49, 57, 99, 51, 51, 98, 97, 55, 102, 53, 100, 102, 54, 50, 51, 57, 49, 97, 54, 102, 48, 102, 48, 54, 55, 99, 53, 55, 49, 98, 100, 54, 99, 48, 51, 101, 56, 51, 102, 56, 49, 99, 100, 49, 54, 54, 101, 53, 53, 102, 101, 48, 52, 51, 52, 50, 54, 97, 49, 99]
```

But the library I'm using gives an error as Invalid Key, Because the library excepts the byte array to be as

```
[4 158 82 11 162 115 50 255 237 89 236 122 52 247 68 212 172 216 106 210 32 129 209 111 133 29 159 53 90 192 154 112 189 193 66 25 195 59 167 245 223 98 57 26 111 15 6 124 87 27 214 192 62 131 248 28 209 102 229 95 224 67 66 106 28]
```

How can I do this in Java, I don't know what the encoding is or how the byte array is being calculated

This is the code

```
String publicKey = "0x049e520ba27332ffed59ec7a34f744d4acd86ad22081d16f851d9f355ac09a70bdc14219c33ba7f5df62391a6f0f067c571bd6c03e83f81cd166e55fe043426a1c
";

NewMessage message1 = Geth.newNewMessage();

message1.setPayload(message.getBytes());
message1.setPublicKey(WhisperHelper.hexStringToByteArray(publicKey));

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Kindly Edit your question and mention the library with the code you have tried.

Comment: What you're doing is converting the ASCII codes of the text to bytes: `0` is 48, `x` is 120, `0` is 48, `4` is 52 etc. Instead you should parse and interpret the string correctly: cut off the `0x`, then loop through the characters, for each 2 chars generate a byte.

Comment: I have edited the quesiton, Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you want

```java
public static byte[] getByteArray(String str) {
    if (!"0x".equals(str.substring(0,2))) {
        return null; // or throw some exception
    } else {
        String tmp = str.substring(2, str.length()-2);
        int bytes = tmp.length() / 2;
        byte[] array = new byte[bytes];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
            byte b = (byte) ((Character.digit(tmp.charAt(i*2), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(tmp.charAt(i*2+1), 16));
            array[i] = b;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

except that numbers greater than 127 (0x7F) will be represented as negative numbers. This is because `byte`s in jave are signed.

So the out put will be

```
[4 -98 82 11 -94 ...
```

Comment: Is there a way by which  I can get the same result for the negative numbers?

Comment: @RohanKeskar not if you want it to store it as an `byte` array, you could however use `short` or `int` as a data type and so get the "correct" numerical value. But this depends on what the framework wants. If it wants an `byte[]` try this approch and report if it was successfull or not.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work, But as the library was open source I made changes in their source code and locally built it to be compatible with my code, Anyways thank you for your help

Comment: @RohanKeskar which lib is it? If it has a GitHub-Repo you might want to raise an Issue explaining them your prolem and how you fixed it in their code

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that showed the best performance...

```
    public static byte[] hex2bytes(String str) {
        if( str == null || str.length() == 0 )
            return null;

        byte[] hex = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        int tmp1, tmp2;

        for(int i=0; i < hex.length; i++) {
            tmp1 = str.charAt(i*2);
            tmp2 = str.charAt(i*2+1);
            hex[i] = (byte)( (tmp1 < 0x41 ? (tmp1 & 0x0F) << 4 : ((tmp1 & 0x0F) + 9) << 4)
                    | (tmp2 < 0x41 ? tmp2 & 0x0F : (tmp2 & 0x0F) + 9) );
        }

        return hex;
    }
```